# Проблема с запуском python 3.6.3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-2.x, anaconda

Я установил новую версию python 3.6.3, до этого у меня стояли python2,python 3.5.2 и anaconda3.

После установки не могу запустит, а установка прошла успешно.

Ввожу команду **python2** получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ввожу команду **python3.5** получаю:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в остальных случаях на картинке: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как мне запустить python3.6.3 версию?**

Comment: А как вы устанавливали-то?

Comment: Вот ссылка, думал поучу django https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/04/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-1.html

Comment: Какая у вас ОС?

Comment: ОС: ununtu 16.04

Comment: Тогда действительно странно

Comment: Все ссылки идут на Anaconda, как я понимаю

Comment: вставляйте текст как текст, чтобы людям с похожей проблемой легче ваш вопрос было найти. Старайтесь болеет информативные заголовки создавать [ask]

Comment: пользуйтесь окружениями

Comment: впервые слышу про ОС ununtu :( @ГамзатРасулов

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется удобнее всего поставить последнюю версию Anaconda (одну) и [создать VirtualEnv окружения для тех версий Python, которые вам нужны](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/):

```
conda update conda

conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda
```

чтобы активировать нужное окружение

```
source activate py36
```

чтобы деактивировать:

```
source deactivate
```

Таким образом вы:

- не трогаете системный Python
- в случае чего можете легко удалить и пересоздать нужное вам окружение
- можете устанавливать различные модули в разные окружения не засоряя остальные
- [можете переносить окружения на другие машины](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207430/how-to-copy-clone-a-virtual-environment-from-server-to-local-machine)

Comment: conda сама откуда-то скачивает последнюю версию питона?

Comment: @andreymal, по-моему да, во всяком случае качает версии модулей для других версий со своего сайта

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в /usr/bin/ (или куда его установили) и проверьте есть ли там python3.6 . Если есть, то значит все ОК можно запускать, но выполнять в терминале /usr/bin/python3.6 script.py неудобно, поэтому для удобства можно создать элиас. Для этого в конец файла ~/.bashrc добавьте строку

```
python36='/usr/bin/python3.6'
```

Перезапустите терминал, теперь питон открывается командой python36 .

Comment: Автор же написал, что у него 3.6 есть и запускается 3.6.2, а он хочет 3.6.3

Comment: У него запускается анаконда, собранная на 3.6.2, а ему нужен чистый питон  3.6.3.